# How to run different Javascript functions on click of specific areas of an div/image

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm wondering if it's possible to run different Javascript functions on click of different areas of a div/image.

For example, if I had an image with dimensions 100px X 100px and I wanted to show an alert whenever the user clicked on the top left 20% of the image (ie, if the user clicked within an area between 0% to 20% down from the top of the image and 0% to 20% in from the left of the image), is that possible?

[image: Area example]

And if so, could I also make a different Javascript alert  function (with a different alert message) run if the user clicks inside the area that's between 30%-40% down from the top of the image, and 50-60% in from the left side of the image?

I need to define the areas by using percentages of the height and width rather than defining the number of pixels explicitly.

Is such a thing possible, and if so, does it require a library to detect the location of the cursor/touch?

Comment: Have you thought about placing some div elements over the image? assign a click event to those elements.... or maybe try tracking x/y position of the mouse and calculate where that would be within the image?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have to put on top your image div elements (tiles) and add to them event listeners or do dynamically calculation of the each click on the image and show alert

Comment: It is possible, you can add a event listener on mouse click and detect target element. then you can get target elements position and calculate places you want and compare to mouse event position.

Comment: Have a look at image map and area tags, though I don't know if the coords support percentual values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position() function on the click event.
If your image has id="myImage" you can do something like this:

```
$("#myImage").click(function(e) {
    var horizpercent = 20;
    var vertpercent = 20;
    var posX = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
    var posY = e.pageY - $(this).position().top;
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    if (posX < width * horizpercent / 100 && posY < height * vertpercent / 100) {
        alert('ye')
    }
});
```

Comment: You should also mention your answer is using a library.... `jQuery` so it would be relevant to explain how to include that library so the OP can at least try your solution.... `jQuery` isn't tagged so offering a jQuery solution explaining how to link to the library would be a smart move, don't assume everyone knows how to do it. It might be the very reason it isn't tagged.

Comment: oooh yes, I always assume jquery if someone's using regular old javascript: go here and download the jquery min and include it in your your layout http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to create multiple overlays over image element.

```
<div class="ovrl-container">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="ovrl ovrl1"></div>
    <div class="ovrl ovrl2"></div>
    <div class="ovrl ovrl3"></div>
</div>
```

`.ovrl-container` has to be `position:relative`, all children `position:absolute`. `.ovrl` has to have `z-index` larger than image in order to capture click instead of image itself. `.ovrl1`, `.ovrl2`, `.ovrl3` should be sized and positioned according to your needs.

In JS part, you are listening to click to `.ovrl1`, `.ovrl2`, `.ovrl3`, jQuery example:

```
$('.ovrl').click(function(){
if( $(this).hasClass('ovrl2') ){
// action only for ovrl2...
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best aproach is to set the image as background of the main div/container, and then using the "display: flex" property, put divs inside the container setting the width and the height in the percentajes that you need. Then you can add event listeners to each div:

```
<div class="container" style="display: flex">
<div id="left-ear" style="height: 20%; width: 30%" onClick="event"></div>
<div id="space-inbetween-ears" [same height and width= 100 - (leftearWitdh 
x2)></div>
<div id="right-ear..." [same as leftEar] onClick="event"></div>
</div>
```

Something like this...

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery-free implementation could look like this:

```js
var click = document.getElementById("click");
click.onclick = function (evt) {
  var xOff = click.offsetLeft;
  var yOff = click.offsetTop;
  var clickedX = evt.pageX - xOff;
  var clickedY = evt.pageY - yOff;
  click.innerHTML = `Clicked on relative pos: ${clickedX}, ${clickedY}`;
};
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px;">Some random height</div>
<div style="height: 50px; background-color: #fdd;" id="click"></div>
```